# Visualizing the complex logarithm

Tags: complex, visualization

I would like to visualize the principal complex logarithm: $f(z)=Log(z)$. I have the following code

```
Table[ParametricPlot[
  With[{z = u + I v}, {Re[Log[z]], Im[Log[z]]}], {u, -10, 10}, {v, n, 
   10}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {-0.5, 3.5}}, Mesh -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 300], {n, 0.1, 1.6, 0.5}]
```

with the result 
[image]

One can see that when the absolute value of the imaginary part is small, the result is far from precise. However, if plot only the image of a single line, it works perfectly well:

```
ParametricPlot[
 With[{z = u + I 0.1}, {Re[Log[z]], Im[Log[z]]}], {u, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 4}, {-0.5, 3.5}}, Mesh -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to fix the first code?

Comment: Increase `PlotPoints`. Try `PlotPoints -> 50`.

Comment: @b3m2a1: that works, thanks!

Comment: Related: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ComplexSlideRule/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using more plot points. I find it takes about 100. Like so.

```
Column[
  Table[
    ParametricPlot[ReIm[Log[u + I v]], {u, -10, 10}, {v, n, 10}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 4}, {-0.5, 3.5}},
      PlotPoints -> 100,
      Mesh -> Automatic,
      ImageSize -> 300],
    {n, 0.1, 1.6, 0.5}]]
```

[image: plots]

Note the simplification of your code.

Comment: I like the "simplification" part. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @b3m2a1's comment, I see that one way to fix it is increasing `PlotPoints`:

```
Table[ParametricPlot[
  With[{z = u + I v}, {Re[Log[z]], Im[Log[z]]}], {u, -10, 10}, {v, n, 
   10}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 4}, {-0.5, 3.5}}, Mesh -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 600, ImageSize -> 300], {n, 0.1, 1.6, 0.5}]
```

which takes a while to run:
[image]

Alternatively, one may use `Show`:

```
Show[Table[
  ParametricPlot[
   With[{z = u + I v}, {Re[Log[z]], Im[Log[z]]}], {u, -10, 10},
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 4}, {-0.5, 3.5}}, Mesh -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> 300], {v, 0.1, 10, 0.2}]]
```

which gives a slightly different result:
[image]

Comment: If you want the mesh to look more like the last one: `ParametricPlot[ReIm[Log[u + I v]], {u, -10, 10}, {v, 1/10, 10}, Axes -> None, Mesh -> Automatic, MeshStyle -> Append[ColorData[97, 1], 1], PlotPoints -> 145, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 4}, {-0.5, 3.5}}, PlotStyle -> None]`