# help me to clarify the transformation of the functions by using Mathematica

Tags: complex, coordinate-transformation

help me to clarify the transformation of the functions by using Mathematica
[image]

Comment: Hello! Previous related questions include [plot of $z \mapsto z^2$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156339), [plot of $z \mapsto 1/z$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137638), [plot of $z \mapsto \log(z)$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155941), [plot of the Cayley map](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241314) and [plot of some other map](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155954). Many approaches use `ParametricPlot`. Have you tried to adapt one of those approaches to your map?

Comment: Incidentally, does [plot of $z \mapsto 1/z$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137638) answer your question, or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

We first define two functions: linesx and linesy that draw the x and y lines in the given strip:

```
xmax = 1;
ymin = 1/4; ymax = 1/2;

linesx[x_] = Table[{x, y}, {y, 1/4, 1/2, 1/16}];
linesy[y_] = Table[{x, y}, {x, -xmax, xmax, 0.1}];

Show[ParametricPlot[linesx[x], {x, -xmax, xmax}], 
 ParametricPlot[linesy[y], {y, ymin, ymax}]]
```

[image]

To get the picture of these lines under the mapping 1/z we use "ComplexExpand":

```
ReIm[1/(x + I y)] // ComplexExpand
```

[image]

We use this to define the functions describing the pictures of the x/y lines:

```
zlinesx[x_] = 
  Table[{x/(x^2 + y^2), -(y/(x^2 + y^2))}, {y, 1/4, 1/2, 1/16}];
zlinesy[y_] = 
  Table[{x/(x^2 + y^2), -(y/(x^2 + y^2))}, {x, -xmax, xmax, 0.1}];

Show[ParametricPlot[zlinesx[x], {x, -xmax, xmax}], 
 ParametricPlot[zlinesy[y], {y, ymin, ymax}]]
```

[image]